# how to set focus to main illustrator window from jsx palette

Tags: javascript, adobe, adobe-illustrator, extendscript

In the extend script, when running palette type window

```
ie - new Window("palette", this.name, undefined)
```

I want to be able to set focus to the main application, ie defocus palette window.
is this doable?
how?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will work in your case. Just a guess:

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// here your palette is activated

// here you activate your doc
doc.activate();
```

Comment: 2 things: 
a. app.activeDocument is inaccessible in palette.
b. no, it does not work, even when sent by bridge talk.

Answer (score 0):

Use visible property exits in app object as below

```
app.visible = true;
```

You can read about more info regarding the same from the following link
https://ai-scripting.docsforadobe.dev/jsobjref/Application/?highlight=app.visible#application-visible

Comment: does nothing at all, since app was already visible.

Comment: Ofcourse, it will do nothing when app is already visible or in focus. But if app is not on in focus, then it will bring it in front.